# Android Studio: Use a Button in a for loop

Tags: java, android-studio, button, arraylist, foreach

I have a class, called "Manager" that passes two values. Once the Integer "mode" and the string "description". This data is then passed to the "description" method. The method contains the array list "test":

```
public class Manager  {

    public int mode;
    public String description;


    public Manager(int mode, String description) {
        this.mode = mode;
        this.description = description;

    }
}
```

This data is then passed to the "description" method. The method contains an arraylist "test":

```
public ArrayList<Manager> description() {
    ArrayList<Manager> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add(new Manager(1,"Test 1"));
    test.add(new Manager(2,"Test 2"));
    test.add(new Manager(3, "Test 3"));
    shuffle(test);
    return test;
}
```

In the method "print", it is iterated over the ArrayList. Depending on which mode is passed, something different is output in the text view.

```
public void print(List<Manager>test) {
    for(Manager i : test) {
        if(i.mode == 1) {
            descriptions.setText("Mode 1 " + i.description);
        } else if(i.mode == 2) {
            descriptions.setText("Mode 2 " + i.description);
        } else if(i.mode == 3D) {
            descriptions.setText(("Mode 3 " + i.description));
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use a button to output a random element from the array list after each click until all elements have been output or until the loop is finished.
So far I have a buttonClicked method that calls the "print" method after each click. But here, the method is restarted after each click.

How can I use the button in the loop so that I get each item only once after each click until the loop is over?

Answer (score 0):

Here still the "*buttonclicked*" method

```
public void buttonClicked(View view) {
    print(description());
}
```

Comment: This should be part of your question, not added as an "answer".

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to use a button to output a random element from the array list after each click until all elements have been output or until the loop is finished. So far I have a buttonClicked method that calls the "print" method after each click. But here, the method is restarted after each click.

This is because you are creating a brand new list with (`description()`) and printing all its contents every single button click.

> How can I use the button in the loop so that I get each item only once after each click until the loop is over?

I don't know what this means.